# Duplicated, como passar mais de um parâmetro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Tenho dois CSV, quero comparar mais de um campo usando `duplicated`. Tem como, ou só posso passar um parâmetro de cada vez?

Segui o direcionamento de Clayton Tosatti e cheguei até aqui, mas agora me deparei com tal dúvida.

```
import pandas as pd
dados = pd.read_csv('gestantes_prenatal.csv')
dados2 = pd.read_csv('cidade_social.csv')
print(dados[['CNS','CNS','CPF','PIS','NASCIMENTO','NOME_DA_MAE']])
print(dados2[['NOME','CNS','CNS','CPF','PIS','NASCIMENTO','NOME_DA_MAE']])
df_aux = pd.concat([dados['CPF'],dados2['CPF']])
```

Até a última linha, perfeito. Mas, queria algo como:

```
df_aux = pd.concat([dados['NOME','PIS','CPF'],dados2['NOME','PIS','CPF']]) 
df_aux[df_aux.duplicated()]
```

Gera este erro:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/hudson/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)<br/>
   2896             try:<br/>
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)<br/>
   2898             except KeyError:<br/>

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('NOME', 'PIS', 'CPF')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)<br/>
<ipython-input-10-5a532f25327c> in <module>()
----> 1 df_aux = pd.concat([dados['NOME','PIS','CPF'],dados2['NOME','PIS','CPF']])

/home/hudson/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:<br/>
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)<br/>
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)<br/>
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):<br/>
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]<br/>

/home/hudson/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)<br/>
   2898             except KeyError:<br/>
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))<br/>
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)<br/>
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:<br/>

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('NOME', 'PIS', 'CPF')
```

**Usei estes** [arquivos](https://mega.nz/#!khVBiaTI!R_3fVilZVPZzAjBTsLjb_ppdMU7ND6bvSlgplMzL0vw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce tem de alterar sua linha de **CONCAT** Hudson

Tenta assim:

```
df_aux = pd.concat([dados[['NOME','PIS','CPF']],dados2[['NOME','PIS','CPF']]]) 
df_aux.loc[df_aux.duplicated()]
```

Comment: O que colchetes não fazem heim?!!! Mais uma vez, muito obrigado **Clayton Tosatti**.

Comment: rsrs eles ajudam muito mesmo, não sei se pegou o conceito, mas basicamente,eles servem para passar colunas como listas, também deve funcionar utilizando uma variável(lista) para armazenar as colunas antes e depois só passar no DF.  `lista = ['NOME', 'PIS', 'CPF']`         |      `df_aux = pd.concat([dados[lista],dados2[lista]])`

Comment: Perfeito, muito show mesmo! Bela linguagem.